# Apache Access Log Ping

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks

An unrelated issue brought me to looking at my Apache 2 access log one morning and much to my chagrin I noticed a 5 second ping with my local host address.  Awesome.  Did I have something running locally to hit my Apache HTTP server or was some joker being a d-ck?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:13:58 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77881
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:14:03 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77881
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:14:08 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77881
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:14:13 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77880
```

Dropping my network connection stopped the access log entries so it looks like there is some bot pinging with no ident or user name.

Anyone have a tool to diagnose what's coming in?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Amazon Cloud is the culprit.  Not sure why they need to ping my Apache server, but will research this even further with them.

Changed my Apache Log format to combined:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

#CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" combined
```

To get better output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:15:06 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77881 "-" "Amazon%20Cloud%20Drive/20131119 CFNetwork/673.4 Darwin/13.2.0 (x86_64) (MacBookAir4%2C2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2014:12:15:36 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 77881 "-" "Amazon%20Cloud%20Drive/20131119 CFNetwork/673.4 Darwin/13.2.0 (x86_64) (MacBookAir4%2C2)"
```

Recycled the Amazon Cloud Drive service and that looks like whatever process that was hanging around pinging the server dropped off.  Curious this did not happen on the countless times I rebooted the machine in the last few days...